# Upgrade to v5, installer cannot find main izpack Installer

Tags: izpack

I have just upgraded to v 5.0.0-beta11 of izPack.

I have updated my configuration so the compiler works.

However, the output jar file throws the following error....

> Could not find or load main class
>   com.izforge.izpack.installer.bootstrap.Installer

**Any suggestions on what I may have missed?**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>

<installation version="5.0"
                     xmlns:izpack="http://izpack.org/schema/installation"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xsi:schemaLocation="http://izpack.org/schema/installation http://izpack.org/schema/5.0/izpack-installation-5.0.xsd">



   <info>
     <appname>appname (2013-09-03)</appname>
     <appversion>20130903_1115</appversion>
     <url>http://google.com</url>
     <authors>
        <author name="steven" email="sbirdranch@yahoo.com"/>
     </authors>
     <uninstaller write="no"/>
   </info>

   <run-privileged condition="izpack.windowsinstall.vista|izpack.windowsinstall.7"/>

   <guiprefs width="700" height="550" resizable="no">
      <modifier key="useButtonIcons" value="no"/>
      <modifier key="useLabelIcons" value="no"/>
      <modifier key="labelGap" value="2"/>
      <modifier key="layoutAnchor" value="NORTHWEST"/>
      <modifier key="useHeadingPanel" value="yes"/>
      <modifier key="headingImageOnLeft" value="no"/>
      <modifier key="headingLineCount" value="1"/>
      <modifier key="headingFontSize" value="1.5"/>
      <modifier key="headingBackgroundColor" value="0x00ffffff"/>
   </guiprefs>  

   <locale>
     <langpack iso3="eng"/>
   </locale>

   <resources>
    <res id="HTMLLicencePanel.licence" src="./packager/pack_license.htm"/>
    <res id="HTMLHelloPanel.hello" src="./packager/pack_welcome.htm"/>
    <res id="Installer.image" src="./packager/pb_wizSplash.png"/>
    <res id="Heading.image" src="./packager/tdkc_gradient.png"/>
    <res id="userInputSpec.xml" src="./packager/userInputSpec.xml"/>
    <res id="TargetPanel.dir" src="./packager/installDir.txt"/>
   </resources>

   <variables>
     <variable name="ShowCreateDirectoryMessage" value="false"/>
   </variables>

   <conditions>
    <condition type="variable" id="checkBox">
            <name>ackVar</name>
            <value>on</value>
    </condition>
    <condition type="or" id="isCheckedCondition">
        <condition type="ref" refid="checkBox"/>
    </condition>
   </conditions>

   <panels>
     <panel classname="HTMLHelloPanel" id="helloPanel"/>
     <panel classname="HTMLLicencePanel" id="licPanel"/>
     <panel classname="UserInputPanel" id="ackSBIRPanel">

     </panel>
     <panel classname="TargetPanel" id="targetPanel"/>
     <panel classname="InstallPanel" id="installPanel"/>
   </panels>


   <packs>
     <pack name="UDK Core" required="yes">
       <description>Core files </description>
       <file src="c:\BUILD_AREA\Build_Tester/tempZip/Build_Tester_20130903_1115_X-win32.win32.x86_64/Build_Tester_Archive_Prefix" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
     </pack>
   </packs>

 </installation>
```

Comment: FYI, version 5 has been in beta for for-ev-ver.  So if you can, it'd be a good idea to use the latest standard release.

Answer (score 1):

> Could not find or load main class *com.izforge.izpack.installer.bootstrap.Installer*

i'd first check build.xml to see if the **izpack-installer-5.0.0-beta11.jar** is included in the classpath or not.

```
<project default="install">
<path id="build.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${DEFAULT_IZPACK_HOME}">
        <include name="lib/*.jar" /> 
    </fileset>
</path>
```